# Pass data from parent to child fragment on ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following Fragment:

```
public class VehicleEditFragment extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private View myView;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private Vehicle vehicle;
    private int vehicle_id;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs, container, false);
        preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_LOGIN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Bundle args = this.getArguments();
        vehicle_id = args.getInt("vehicle_id");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) myView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        getActivity().setTitle("Vehiculo");
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new VehicleBasicInfoFragment(), "Datos básicos");
        adapter.addFrag(new VehicleEquipmentServicesFragment(), "Equipamiento y Servicios");
        adapter.addFrag(new VehicleExplanationFragment(), "Descripción");
        adapter.addFrag(new VehicleLocationFragment(), "Localización");
        adapter.addFrag(new VehicleImagesFragment(), "Fotos");
        adapter.addFrag(new VehicleRatesFragment(), "Tarifas");
        adapter.addFrag(new VehicleDisponibilityFragment(), "Disponibilidad");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    private class FindVehicleInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String token = preferences.getString(Config.TOKEN, "");

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            //toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            if(vehicle.getError() != 0){
                if(vehicle.getError() == Config.JWT_EXPIRED){
                    //logout();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            getActivity().getString(R.string.session_expired),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    //toast.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.find_pendings_errror));
                   // toast.show();
                }
            }else {
                //setUpAdapter();
            }
            //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            vehicle = DBConnect.GetVehicleInfo(token, vehicle_id);
            return "done";
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is to pass info of the Vehicle class to all the child fragments that I have. The perfect aproach would be to be able to connect the parent with each child and get the vehicle info from the parent to the child. Is that possible? or is there any other way to pass the info to each child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming Vehicle class is one that you wrote, I would recommend making that class implement the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface.

Then, since the object is Parcelable, you can pass it into a Fragment using a new instance method:

```
public static VehicleBasicInfoFragment NewInstance(Vehicle vehicle) {
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putParcelable("vehicleKey", vehicle);

   VehicleBasicInfoFragment fragment = new VehicleBasicInfoFragment();
   fragment.setArguments(args);

   return fragment;
}
```

Then, you can retrieve that info from your onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super(savedInstanceState);

   Vehicle vehicle = getArguments.getExtras().getParcelable("vehicleKey");
}
```

Once you've updated your child fragments to have their own NewInstance method like that, you can update your ViewHolder creation like this:

```
adapter.addFrag(VehicleBasicInfoFragment.NewInstance(vehicleObject), "Datos básicos");
```